# Resizing an image with mini_magick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

My service has both a web version and an iPhone version. On the iPhone, we ensure that users submit a square version by having it crop when it uploads. We are allowing uploads on the website as well, but we do not have such a feature.

As such, I would like to scale any uploaded image into fitting a 612 * 612 area. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I am using Ruby / mini_magick

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd just use the `resize` method from MiniMagick, there's an example on the Github page:

> https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick

Presumably you have the image as a bunch of bytes in memory so something like this:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.read(your_image_bytes)
image.resize('612x612')
scaled_image_bytes = image.to_blob
# Or image.write(filename)
```

MiniMagick uses standard ImageMagick geometry strings for sizing and, from the [fine manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry), a `WxH` geometry:

> Maximum values of height and width given, aspect ratio preserved.

so using `'612x612'` will scale the image to fit within a 612px square while preserving the aspect ratio.

You could also use [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) to allow your web users to crop the their uploaded images to fit into a square.

Comment: Another gem worth looking into is CarrierWave, which takes a fair amount of the pain out of working with MiniMagick.  There are several options including resize_and_pad, which will ensure you have a square image, but without cropping off anything important.  We use this in conjunction with JCrop.